# Cómo hacer el Password Reset Con un campo diferente a email Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel

Tengo en mi tabla *users* dos campos de emails, por lo que a uno lo llamo **company_email** y el otro **personal_email**, el login ya lo tengo con el campo **company_email**. Sin embargo quiero ahora que se pueda restablecer la contraseña introduciendo dicho campo para que envíe el *token* a ese email.

Answer (score 0):

Tendrás que hacer un override de lo siguiente:

**app/Http/Controllers/Auth/PasswordController.php**

Todos ellos son métodos de **Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ResetsPasswords**

Revisalos por si me dejo algunos, hay que cambiar el valor email por company_email.

Tambén debes retocar las vistas cambiando email por company_email

/resources/views/auth/emails/password.blade.php
/resources/views/auth/passwords/email.blade.php
/resources/views/auth/passwords/reset.blade.php

Te pongo las funciones a agregar en **app/Http/Controllers/Auth/PasswordController.php**:

```
protected function validateSendResetLinkEmail(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, ['company_email' => 'required|email']);
}

protected function getSendResetLinkEmailCredentials(Request $request)
{
    return $request->only('company_email');
}

protected function getSendResetLinkEmailFailureResponse($response)
{
    return redirect()->back()->withErrors(['company_email' => trans($response)]);
}

public function showResetForm(Request $request, $token = null)
{
    if (is_null($token)) {
        return $this->getEmail();
    }

    $email = $request->input('company_email');

    if (property_exists($this, 'resetView')) {
        return view($this->resetView)->with(compact('token', 'company_email'));
    }

    if (view()->exists('auth.passwords.reset')) {
        return view('auth.passwords.reset')->with(compact('token', 'company_email'));
    }

    return view('auth.reset')->with(compact('token', 'company_email'));
}

protected function getResetValidationRules()
{
    return [
        'token' => 'required',
        'company_email' => 'required|email',
        'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:6',
    ];
}

protected function getResetCredentials(Request $request)
{
    return $request->only(
        'company_email', 'password', 'password_confirmation', 'token'
    );
}

protected function getResetFailureResponse(Request $request, $response)
{
    return redirect()->back()
        ->withInput($request->only('company_email'))
        ->withErrors(['company_email' => trans($response)]);
}
```